# Uniqueness of solution of IVP in a certain domain.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the IVP $$y’=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0, x\in\Bbb R$$ where $f$ is continuous on an open connected set $D\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and begin Lipschitz on any rectangle inside $D$. Then the above IVP has a unique solution (say) $ y$ in a certain neighbourhood $(x_0-h,x_0+h)$of $x_0$ if   $(x_0,y_0)\in D$,  $h $ is as given in Picard uniqueness theorem. **Now my question is that can $y$ be continuously extend over whole domain $D$ in a unique way i.e. will be unique until it remains inside $D?$.**

According to me it’s true as if $(x_0+h, f(x_0+h)\in D$ then again using uniqueness theorem on IVP $$y’=f(x,y), y(x_0+h)=f(x_0+h)$$ we can uniquely extend $y$ at the right end point of $(x_0-h,x_0+h)$ and similarly at left end point . Do the same process unitill $y$ remains inside $D$ and hence we have unique extension of $y$ over $D$ . Please suggest am i right ? If wrong please provide counter-example. Thank you .

Comment: Where does $x$ live? Is it in $\mathbb{R}$ (then yes, you can use the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf). On the other hand, if you want to know about higher dimensions, then the answer is no, you cannot extend in general to the whole domain (consider $f(x, y)= 1/x$ on a suitable domain in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I edit about domain .

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $y’=\frac{1}{x}, x_0>0,y_0>0$ has solution $logx+c$ which is unique in $[a,\infty), a>0?$

Comment: The logarithm is not globally defined on - say - the complex plane with a ball removed around the origin. That is why I asked about the nature of $x$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven sir I am asking about real solutions....

Comment: @SeverinSchraven now can I say that my concept is true if $x$ is real variable ?

Comment: Yes, I did say so already in my first comment :)